# change empty array element to a value

Tags: php

i have an array like this
Array ([0]=>'some values'[1]=>'')

I want to change the empty elemnt of an array to a value of 5

how can I do that

thanks

Comment: Which of those PHP versions are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know at which position it is, just do:

```
$array[1] = 5;
```

If not, loop through it and check with [`===` for value and type equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
foreach($array as &$element) { //get element as a reference so we can change it
    if($element === '') { // check for value AND type
        $element = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

5.3 version

```
$arr = array_map(function($n) { return !empty($n) ? $n : 5; }, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this:

```
function emptyToFive($value) {
    return empty($value) ? 5 : $value;       
}

$arr = array_map(emptyToFive, $arr);
```

As of PHP 5.3, you can do:

```
$func = function($value) {
    return empty($value) ? 5 : $value;       
};
$arr = array_map($func, $arr);
```

EDIT: If `empty` does not fit your requirements, you should perhaps change the condition to `$value === ''` as per @Felix's suggestion.

Comment: I'd say, `empty` is not the right function here. It will also return true, for `0`, `'0'` and `FALSE` which are very likely not empty values in this case.

Comment: You might be right, I'd say it really depends on the OP's exact requirements. I've edited that in.

Answer (score -2):

This `$array[1] = 5;`